# Offline webapp - Storing JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to make a simple web browser console program that would run COMPLETELY OFFLINE.

In that program, I'd like to store some data in the form of an **array of objects** so that I could easily pick a random object.

My problem is that even though I looked up the internet, including this question [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage) and this question [Offline webapp. How to store data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007097/offline-webapp-how-to-store-data) , I still don't have any clue of what to do.

**I'd like to find a way to easily add objects to my array and save those changes so that when I open the browser again, the data set would be intact.**

I understand that HTML5's local storage only stores data in the form of strings, so what should I do ?

Should I use Node.js ? If so, how can I send back the data to my web browser Javascript file so that I can display things in the browser ?

Comment: http://thejackalofjavascript.com/getting-started-with-node-webkit-apps/

Comment: If you are going to write an offline appliation. Indexdb will be the best storage option (in my opinion)

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize your array of objects using [`JSON.stringify`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc836459(v=vs.94).aspx) so that it is stored as a string in Web Storage and deserialize it upon retrieval using [`JSON.parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/cc836466(v=vs.94).aspx):

```
var arrayOfObjects = [
    { foo: 'hello' },
    { bar: 'world' },
    { baz: 'dinosaurs' }
];

function storeInWebStorage(key, arr) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(arr));
}

function retrieveFromWebStorage(key) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
}

storeInWebStorage(arrayOfObjects);
```

Keep in mind though that [there's a limit on the amount of data you can store in Web Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2989284/404623), and this limit differs between browsers.

Comment: Thanks, I actually didn't know that JSON.stringify was working with an array as an input :)