# how to create project work in online and offline mode in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create a project in MVC that works in online mode and offline mode for example when a user work in offline there is no connectivity of the internet available 
then all data stored on the local machine when internet connectivity available then all the data push on the server.

Please help how can I do this.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to work offline ?
What is the purpose of your application ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of data should be stored offline? Data can be stored in many different ways, but the best way may depend on what kind of data you want to store, and how to synchronize it back online at a later time.

Comment: @Aliz: I want to create hospital management website the main purpose of my application is that if our application uses I remote area there is no internet connectivity but application work

Comment: @lars: I want to store data like patient registration, consultation details, lab details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Offline webapp. How to store data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007097/offline-webapp-how-to-store-data)

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to use third party **sync service**/SQL sync/Microsoft sync service etc.

you have to **create** other **project** which run at certain time and **execute your sync process** for local system to Live server database and vice versa.

you should have to use GUID to store your unique(PK) value, because at time of sync live server table has incoming data from any local server, so your local db tables pk no more usable in live server db table

**Note:** For this type of offline and online sync process your PK column should be type of **VARCHAR(36)** and store **GUID value**